# Open source Eclipse plugin that identifies and maps the code base against different layers

Tags: open-source, eclipse

I need an open source Eclipse plugin which could fulfill these requirements:

1. Identify and map the code base against different layers (UI, Service, Persistence etc.)
2. UCM representing the business logic
3. Business rules in BPMN notation and be able to be exported into an Excel
4. Aiding in the generation of test cases from UCM

Comment: Your code base can only be mapped into layers if it has been written that way and in that case you can use either directory structure or naming convention to distinguish layers. Why on earth would you wish to export BPMN to __Excel__? Also you don't mention which programming language(s) need to be supported.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Requirement are there to export BPMN to excel. Programming language is JAVA.